# Open a new window with <exec> in Apache Ant

Tags: ant, cmd

I have a build.xml for my ant in which I use

```
<exec executable="cmd">
  <arg line = "start"/>
  <arg value ="/c test3.bat"/>
</exec>
```

to start the given bat-file.
This works fine, but  what I really want is that it opens the test3.bat in a new cmd-window. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works like that =

```
<exec executable="cmd">
  <arg value="/c"/>
  <arg value = "start"/>
  <arg value ="test3.bat"/>
</exec>
```

In case oft doubt,  use multiple `<arg value=.../>` for the parameters instead of `<arg line=.../>`,
works better.

Comment: Wow, thank you!
I tried different things similar to that, but nothing worked....
Most likely because I had the `start` before the `/c`